# HBase error disabled security features are not available

Tags: security, hadoop, authorization, hbase, kerberos

Configured secure HBase-1.1.2 with Hadoop-2.7.1 on Windows. When i enable authorization referring [Configuring HBase Authorization](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-3-2/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_8_3.html), getting **ERROR: DISABLED: Security features are not available** exception.

I have set the authorization configurations as below,

**Configuration**

```
<property>
     <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
     <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name> 
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
```

[image]

But HBase Authorization works fine when i tried with HBase-0.98.13 version. Some one help me to enable HBase Authorization in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountered with the same problem as I was not able to grant privileges to any other users. Mine was Kerberized Hadoop cluster I did following changes to make it work.

```
hbase.security.authentication=kerberos
hbase.security.authorization=true
```

Then re-deployed the configurations then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountered with the same problem as I was not able to grant privileges to any other users. Mine was Kerberized Hadoop cluster.In addition to,My zookeeper was kerberized.So I do the following things:
firstly,you need stop your hbase.
Add the following to {$ZOOKEEPER_CONF_DIR}/jaas.conf:

```
Client{
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/var/local/hadoop/zookeeper-3.4.8/conf/keytabs/hbase.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    useTicketCache=true
    principal="hbase/zte1.zdh.com@ZDH.COM";
};
```

(My hbase principal is:hbase/zte1.zdh.com@ZDH.COM,username must be same)

then,use zkCli.sh command Line,next you can use: `rmr /hbase` to rmove the hbase directory,then start your hbase service,you will solve this problem.

Comment: When i do client authentication for zookeeper, it cannot login with keytab. But kinit does. What's wrong? I am a windows user.